# Which of these ND filtered images do you think is more accurate? (sample images included)

Tags: white-balance, color-correction, neutral-density, colorchecker

As a followup to my [previous question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/117214/for-a-given-lens-camera-will-a-nd-filter-always-need-same-wb-correction-in-all); there has been [interest expressed](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/117345/how-to-use-x-rite-colorchecker-with-sony-a7r-iv#comment226268_117356) in the results of my ND filter tests.

First, I should clarify that the heavy color cast shown in that post was from a single coated B+W filter (6-stop) purchased 5 years ago (77mm, not that it matters). I don't know if it was counterfeit, but it was obtained from Amazon (not a reseller).

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XO1tKhumtQRL3cv3mrQ7GcgM_iPjvLWT) are the raw images from a new test I did, shooting 4 different angles in the mid-afternoon using 3 test cases at each angle:

1) No filter
2) B+W MRC Nano (82mm) 6-stop (obtained from B&H)
3) Breakthrough X4 (82mm) 6-stop (obtained from Breakthrough direct, thru Amazon)

I spent a few hours analyzing this data. My conclusions:

1) X-Rite Camera Checker is significantly better than Adobe's alternative, in terms of consistency and correctness. Using X-Rite, I was able to make filter and no-filter shots look pretty much identical, and also realistic. The Adobe profiles tended to be far more saturated. Possibly more visually pleasing, but probably not accurate, and also not quite consistent; they didn't always make filter version look the same as no-filter.
2) The B+W and Breakthrough filters both seem pretty good in terms of color cast. They both have maybe a *very* small cast (nothing as bad as my other single-coated B+W) that is easily corrected but also barely noticeable if uncorrected. I think the B+W leans warm and the Breakthrough leans cold, but I'm not sure. If forced to choose, I think the B+W is slightly better (smaller cast, and I prefer warm). I like the ergonomics of the Breakthrough (the knurling around the outside of the ring), and I like that it's made in San Fran near my home. But I dislike that it's a new unproven company, and I also dislike that it seems slightly more optically dense than the B+W (no idea which one is actually closer to a true 6-stop, but I'd rather err on the side of too fast at this level). I'll probably return the Breakthrough and keep the B+W (and also replace my old 77mm B+W with a new MRC Nano).

I'm curious what others' conclusions are on my points above, i.e.
1) X-Rite vs Adobe
2) B+W vs Breakthrough

EDIT: Per request, here are some renders from my machine. I've only included the 4th angle of all my raw shots, since it contains the most variety of color and objects behind the passport.

**The 3 rows, top to bottom are:**
No filter
B+W filter
Breakthrough filter

**The 3 columns, left to right are:**
Standard "Adobe Color" profile from ACR
Custom profile from Adobe's DNG Profile Editor
Custom profile from X-Rite's Color Checker

Note that every custom profile was created for that specific photo (i.e. 6 custom profiles are involved in the grid below).

Also note that with with every render, I clicked "auto" in ACR. I suspect this may cause some controversy, but at best it fixes any small exposure differences. And it does seem fairly consistent in how it operates... whatever criteria those are. Also note that this did not radically change the deltas between the results. Even at "default"... the results are the same... but the exposures all look slightly off.

So... since I prefer the X-Rite results, that means I'm focusing mostly on the right column. Within that column, I'm trying to figure out which of the two bottom cells (filtered) most closely matches the top (unfiltered). And I think that is the middle cell (B+W), barely.

[image]

Comment: I've gotten a fake B+W filter ordering directly from amazon. They mix their own inventory with that of third parties, and have for quite some time. Whether they were already doing it five years ago, I do not know.

Comment: @MichaelC yes I've been hearing that in the past couple years and have since stopped ordering certain things from them for that reason. :-( This 5-year old filter also has a really weird cloudy discoloration on it after infrequent use and good care. That seems inconsistent with B+W's reputation.

Comment: @MichaelC I did actually order a7R IV and Sony 24-105mm thru Amazon 6 months ago... they appear to work great, so if they are counterfeits they are impressive. I think it's probably far more common on simple devices like filters. But just to be safe, I now order lenses only through B&H.

Comment: Cameras and lenses are controlled by pricing agreements between "authorized sellers" and the manufacturers. It's not easy for counterfeiters to sell them in volume on amazon because they can't undercut the price of real cameras/lenses. They're also very low volume complex products selling at high prices. Even counterfeiters must spend a lot to make a functional fake digital camera. The risk is far too great of fake inventory already shipped to amazon being destroyed when caught to make it worth it on such items. Not so much for fake filters that they can make for pennies each.

Comment: Without the data from how the color calibration processes chose to interpret the raw image files, your samples are useless. We can't see how your computer processes them to see what you see when you view them. [There's no such thing as "THE" raw file as a viewable image.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/100927/15871) There are only a near countless number of possible interpretations of that raw data. We can't see the specific interpretations you're asking us to compare.

Comment: I'd suggest you upload your JPEG conversions of what you're looking at on your screen (which is already a JPEG-like conversion of the information in the raw image file) directly into the question.

Comment: I understand that my computer will display different representation of RAW images than yours. But are you suggesting that a RAW profiler will yield different results for the same RAW on different machines? That wouldn't make any sense... the color spectrum captured by the sensor is agnostic to my computer, as is the "right" interpretation of that spectrum. Also, I'm not asking for thoughts on what I see on my screen, I'm asking for thoughts on deltas. If filter A produces consistently warm results and filter B cold... shouldn't anybody on any machine be able to verify from the RAW images?

Comment: In fact, I am specifically curious that on `machine X`, a user will observe (or not) similar things as me (i.e. `filter A` is warm and `filter B` is cold, but `filter ?` is best). And similarly on `machine Y`. All using the camera's raw output as a starting point. I don't want my computer to be a variable in this experiment, only my camera, its raw output, the two filters tested, and the two calibration softwares mentioned. I realize that puts a larger onus on the answerer, and I'll be happy to accept fewer answers as a result of that cost. :-)

Comment: That said, I can try to upload a comparison render. There are 24 variants though (4 angles, 3 filters, and 2 profilers). I'll see if I can somehow make that viewable easily.

Comment: Every raw conversion application can, and will, render the same raw file differently. There is no "neutral" or "correct" rendering of a raw file that is any more valid than any other without proper color management, which would include some type of calibration target or set of color multipliers that tells the rendering app what color multipliers to use. Those aren't contained in the raw file information. What camera's AWB *guesses* they should be *might* be used by some rendering applications, but not all will use that information.

Comment: Using the same color temperature and tint settings, one can see the difference, but it is impossible to tell if one is too warm or the other is too cool without a neutral gray or white (with no channels fully saturated) target in the scene.

Comment: There is no "correct" starting point for interpreting the raw information. What you see on your screen is *never* the raw data, it is one specific interpretation of that data that uses the default settings of your viewing application or your camera's JPEG engine (if your application is showing you the JPEG preview). Please read the link that has been included in comments above. See also: [What does an unprocessed RAW file look like?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105271/15871) and [RAW files store 3 colors per pixel, or only one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86170/15871).

Comment: How did you create/edit the Adobe DNG Color Profile?

Comment: Had you already created an X-Rite profile when you did the pictures in the first and second columns? Did you do separate X-Rite profiles for each of the three images?

Comment: Every profile was created specifically for the photo in question, using either Adobe's DNG Color Profile Editor or X-Rite's ColorChecker. Edited this into the question.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, with proper color management, the different tints of each filter do not significantly matter. Both filters can be properly corrected to match a calibrated image with no filter. That's because your color management software is adjusting each one differently to give the same result based on what it thinks the color *should* be.

The most obvious differences in the sample images are that, for whatever reason, the images made using the DNG Color Profiler are much more saturated than the images made using the Adobe Standard and X-Rite Color Checker Profiles. Those two are probably more accurate renderings of the scene than the DNG Profile. It's fine if you want to boost saturation as you process raw files, but it's usually better to get as accurate a rendering as possible with the color profile applied and then increase saturation later in the process.

> Also note that with with every render, I clicked "auto" in ACR. I suspect this may cause some controversy, but at best it fixes any small exposure differences.

In the far left column, whatever minor differences there are almost certainly more attributable to the differences in the scene (no filter box, filter box with mostly blue and white colors both in sunlight and in shade, filter box with red, gold, and white colors in sunlight and shade) than the differences between no filter, the B+W filter, and the Breakthrough filter. **The entire contents of a scene can affect the Auto White Balance function of the Adobe Standard Color Profile, which analyzes the entire scene and attempts to set color temperature and tint based on clues in the scene.**

In the middle column you've used Adobe's DNG color profiler, which should be based on a color profile you created/edited. If you didn't edit anything in the DNG Color Profile, it's still using the default color profile for your specific model camera and, again, guessing at what part of the image should be neutrally white or gray. I assume you used the color checker with the color profiler to create a custom profile? I've never used DNG files or created a color profile in Adobe (I use different raw conversion tools).

In the right column you've used the X-Rite software to sample each of the squares on the color checker and correct each image to make the colors display what the X-Rite software says they should be. If you properly created an individual profile for each image, then there should be virtually no differences in color between each of the three frames, and there aren't.